# Properly join 2 tables with multiple result

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables that needs to be joined wherein both of them can have as many of the other table.

A resident can have as many as relative and the relative can have as many as resident.

I need your opinion if this is a good way to join them properly. What I've done is I have a separate table that saves their respective ids.

I've attached a picture of reference. Thanks!

[table picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veCpH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a classic relational implementation for a many-to-many relationship, implemented with an intersection table.